# Function to take argument bound by ANY of several traits

Tags: generics, rust

I have a function (let's call it `foo<T>(x: &mut T)`) that needs to call a particular method on it's argument (let's call it `x.bar()`). Problem is, that there are *two* different *traits* that define method `bar` with precisely the same semantics (let's call them `A::Bar` and `B::Bar`). So I want the function to accept either `A::Bar` or `B::Bar`.

If they were structs, I could simply define a new trait for them. If only one was trait, I could define a new trait with blanket definition (`impl<T> My::Bar for T where T: A::Bar`) and explicit implementation for any remaining structs. But they are *two traits* and two blanket `impl`s are not allowed. Is there any other way to work around this? Perhaps by `match` with different types or something?

Obviously they are **not my traits**. It is a bug in the library that defines them. I am going to report it. But I would still like a workaround for until it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by writing a wrapper around your `&T` that explicitly controls *which* `bar` you want to be called.  I'm not aware of any *simpler* method of doing this.  The below code *should* be efficient, since it uses static dispatch.

```
trait A {
    fn bar(&self);
}

trait B {
    fn bar(&self);
}

// This will be our "common ground" trait.
trait Bar {
    #[inline(always)]
    fn bar(&self);
}

// The Bar wrapper for A.
struct ABar<'a, T: 'a + A>(&'a T); //'

impl<'a, T: 'a + A> Bar for ABar<'a, T> { //'
    #[inline(always)]
    fn bar(&self) { self.0.bar(); }
}

// The Bar wrapper for A.
struct BBar<'a, T: 'a + B>(&'a T); //'

impl<'a, T: 'a + B> Bar for BBar<'a, T> { //'
    #[inline(always)]
    fn bar(&self) { self.0.bar(); }
}

// Example type that implements both A and B.
struct Thingy;

impl A for Thingy {
    fn bar(&self) { println!("A::bar()"); }
}

impl B for Thingy {
    fn bar(&self) { println!("B::bar()"); }
}

// Note: I've removed the reference here since the implementations of Bar
// are just wrappers around a reference.
fn foo<T: Bar>(x: T) {
    x.bar();
}

fn main() {
    let thingy = Thingy;
    // Note that we have to be *explicit* about the wrapper.
    foo(ABar(&thingy));
    foo(BBar(&thingy));
}
```

Comment: The call must be `foo(&thingy)`, that's the point of the question. `thingy` is _either_ `A::Bar` _or_ `B::Bar`, _never both_.

Comment: But, as you said, that's impossible.  Coherence won't let you make a blanket `impl` for both simultaneously; hence the wrapper.  You need *some* kind of unifying trait, and you need a layer of type indirection to allow you to implement that unifying trait for both `A` and `B`.  If you really can't change anything about `foo`, then the answer as far as I can see is: "you can't, give up".

Comment: Then just make _that_ an answer.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can do it with static dispatch, right now. You might be able to use trait objects, instead (depending on the object-safety of your traits).

i.e. if you define an enum:

```
enum Bars<'a> {
    Bbar(&'a b::Bar),
    Cbar(&'a c::Bar),
}
```

you could have your function written like this:

```
fn foo(bars: &Bars) -> u32 {
    use Bars::*;
    match bars {
        &Bbar(b) => b.foo(),
        &Cbar(c) => c.foo(),
    }
}
```

[playpen example](http://is.gd/0eVvIe)

Comment: I believe static and dynamic dispatch can do exactly the same things, currently. The problem is that there are two, _different_, traits, that define the method.

Comment: The call must be `foo(&thingy)`, that's the point of the question. thingy is _either_ `A::Bar` _or_ `B::Bar`, _never both_.

Comment: b::Bar and c::Bar in my example *are* two different traits that define the same method. And an enum is expressing that it's *either* &b::Bar *or* &c::Bar. The signature of foo is saying just what you said: accept something that either implements b::Bar or c::Bar. Except that the dispatch of the method is done at runtime (at compile time you don't know what actual type implementing b::Bar or c::Bar you're going to use, so rustc can't monomorphize foo)

Comment: Therefore the function does _not_ accept either `A::Bar` or `B::Bar`, it accepts `Bars`, and therefore it does not qualify as answer.